# UK visa for non-EU citizen living in Germany

Tags: uk, turkish-citizens

My fiancée lives in Germany. She is Turkish and has a 4-year-old who's a German citizen. She has a residence permit in Germany. Can I ask how I can bring her to the UK?

Comment: What is _your_ nationality? Do _you_ live in the UK? Are you talking about a short trip to the UK, or moving there to live indefinitely? In the latter case it's a question for [expats.SE].

Comment: I have British nationality and I live in  .uk  my fiance she will move to uk thx